# How to start an automaticaly angular build process after save in PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

The used IDEs are: Intellij Idea and PyCharm

I use AngularJS as frontend and Django as a Server. If I create/change something in in angularJS foler (app for example) I have to run `ng build --output-path=..\..\static\angularjs` to build the bundles to my static folder.

Is there a listener or a hook, to run this command automaticaly if I click on 'Save' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **File Watcher** (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/file-watchers.html) for **ng** (make sure to specify a full path to **ng** executable as a *Program*) and disable 'Immediate synchronization' option so that the program is triggered on explicit Save All/changing focus only